# error in android 9 protected doInBackground

Tags: java, android, json

I'm having trouble using these codes on Android 9 (work fine in lower versions)

Exits immediately and below error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.banehmall.application, PID: 2092
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter;
    at org.scribe.services.DatatypeConverterEncoder.encode(DatatypeConverterEncoder.java:10)
    at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.bytesToBase64String(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:51)
    at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.doSign(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:46)
    at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.getSignature(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:32)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getSignature(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:151)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.addOAuthParams(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:75)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.signRequest(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:126)
    at com.ciyashop.library.apicall.PostApi$postAPiCall.doInBackground(PostApi.java:109)
    at com.ciyashop.library.apicall.PostApi$postAPiCall.doInBackground(PostApi.java:40)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-5XvyXjUfi1L5D2K7385M5A==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.banehmall.application-.
```

.
.

After adding this (*commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10*)library, app worked but the data is not received from the server and have 
this log

```
E/Exception is: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.
E/EGL_emulation: tid 2357: eglSurfaceAttrib(1354): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeb2e4dc0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
E/EGL_emulation: tid 2357: eglSurfaceAttrib(1354): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeb2e4e20, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
E/getHomeDataResponse is: OAuthConnectionException
E/getHomeDataGson Exception is: Value OAuthConnectionException of type java.lang.String cannot be                 
converted to JSONObject
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=899ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=1587234779362, Vsync=1587568112682,         
OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=1587582802287, 
AnimationStart=1587582869695, PerformTraversalsStart=1587582992031, DrawStart=1587644518429, 
SyncQueued=1587720147467, SyncStart=1587740410691, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1587740635430, 
SwapBuffers=1588088691627, FrameCompleted=1588154607644, DequeueBufferDuration=199000, 
QueueBufferDuration=417000,
```

thank you so mach

Comment: Take a look at: [how to use java core lib not supported in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125322/how-to-use-java-core-lib-not-supported-in-android), [Alternatives for DatatypeConverter in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342136/alternatives-for-datatypeconverter-in-android)

Comment: @Michał Ziober thanks i try but not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found the solution to this problem. In Android 9(28 and up)uses HTTPS ,if your server uses HTTP this error is happen. answer is writing the following code in the manifest

```
<application
    .
    .
    .
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

if not work use Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: too late, but still not work. any suggesstion?